# How to check cancan permission on ActiveAdmin custom page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, activeadmin, cancancan

I've the following `Ability`:

```
can :manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'My Page'
```

And it is working fine, but I want to check if the user has the ability to manage this `ActiveAdmin::Page` in different pages. So, when I used the following:

```
can? :manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'My Page'
```

It returned `true` for any page even if it does not exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out a way, it looks weird because it uses *register_page* but it is working:

```
can? :manage, (ActiveAdmin::register_page 'My Page')
```

Answer (score 9):

The code

```
can? :manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'My Page'
```

checks if the current user can manage an instance of `ActiveAdmin::Page` whose `name` attribute is equal to *My Page*. That is exactly the condition you stated in your abilities file, and that is why it always returns `true`.

In case you want to know if a user can or cannot access a specific page (which is what I think you are trying to do) you should ask "can I manage *this* page?" instead of "can I manage a page whose name is *My Page*?". In the former you are talking about a specific page, and in the later you are talking about pages with a certain characteristic.

In order to ask CanCan whether the current user can access a specific page, just ask:

```
can? :manage, my_specific_page
```

where `my_specific_page` needs to be an instance of `ActiveAdmin::Page`.

Comment: But I want to used it in a different page!

Comment: `my_specific_page` needs to be an instance of `ActiveAdmin::Page`, not necessarily the page you are currently visiting. Just have to make sure that `my_specific_page` is the page where you want to know permissions

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the question now what is the right syntax to access ActiveAdmin page instance?

Answer (score 1):

After I applied register_page solution, the menu dropdowns extended to individual menu links.

This github issue leads me to answer.
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4783#issuecomment-479562966

I solved like this.

```rb
def find_custom_page(name)
   ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.find{|r| r.resource_name.name == name }
end

can? :manage, (find_custom_page 'MyPage')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share what I did for my case:

```
# ability.rb

can(:manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'Page Title')
```

And in the ActiveAdmin page:

```
action_item :specific_page, only: :show, if: proc { authorized?(:manage, controller.instance_variable_get(:@specific_page)) } do
  link_to 'Page Title', "/admin/..."
end
...  
controller do
  def show
    @specific_page = ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.select { |resource| resource.resource_label == 'Page Title' }.first
  end
end
```